# Question on PCI Express(PCIe) configuration space access on VirtualBox

Tags: operating-system, virtualbox, pci-e, acpi

Hi I'm trying to access the PCIe configuration space with MMIO method on a kernel base.

Before I drop my question, my platform is Windows 10, VirtualBox 6.0.10.

My virtual machine set as default except the following:

1. chipset choosed ICH9
2. Core number set to 4
3. Memory set to 1GB
4. Added IDE controller(no HD connected)

After boot, the printing shows that valid memory address are:0x0~0x9FC00 and 0x100000~0x3FEF0000 as displayed in following screen shot.

[image]

While type 1 is RAM, 2 is ROM or Reserved, 3 is ACPI Reclaim Memory and 4 is ACPI NVS Memory.

Furthermore I retrieved base address of the PCIe configuration memory map base address from MCFG as showed in the following screen shot.

[image]

It can be seen that:

1. The configuration space base is 0x3F000000 which overlap with the valid memory space.
2. The first 8 byte of 0x3F000000~0x3F000008 is all 0, which should be first 8 byte of bus:0, device:0, function:0.

So whether I should not use VirtualBox, or I should do some other operations to enable PCIe MMIO accessibility of configuration space?

Thanks so much!!

Comment: Everything seems correct. Did you try to add any other device behind PCI Root Bridge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably parsed the "MFCG ACPI table" incorrectly, or used the wrong (virtual?) address for the "MFCG ACPI table" and forgot to check signature and checksum.

The "Base_addr:" doesn't make sense, and the "Start_PCI_bus: 0, End_PCI_bus: 0" doesn't make sense either.

Comment: Start bus 0 followed by the same value for end bus makes sense for certain platforms. Why not?

Comment: @0andriy: Assume you're designing a circuit to handle PCIE MMIO that will be added to your company's "circuit library" so other people can cut&paste that circuit into 10 different chipsets that will be used for 200 different motherboards; where any PCI device that is attached (by chipset designer, motherboard manufacturer, computer OEM or end user) could include its own "PCI to PCI bridge" (resulting in a secondary bus number). A circuit that only supports one bus number would be so "niche" that it isn't economically viable.

Comment: @0andriy: Note that a (hypothetical) "PCIE MMIO handling circuit" would mostly be converting "read/write to physical address" transactions from CPU/s into "read/write PCI config space" special transactions on the PCI bus; and would begin with a typical address detector (like `if( (address & ~MASK) == BASE)`) and then probably just modifies a "transaction type" field in the transaction's header and applies the mask to the address info in the transaction (`address &= MASK;`). It probably costs literally nothing (no extra transistors) for the circuit to support multiple bus numbers.

Comment: So you agree that it *does* make sense in some cases, right? (At least i know such platforms in the wild)

Comment: @0andriy: Cases where "PCI-E MMIO for only bus only" might make are limited to cases where ACPI and PCI-E don't make sense (e.g. internal bus of a custom SoC with no expansion options).

Comment: @0andriy: Of course for VirtualBox specifically; it can't make sense (e.g. advanced features like "PCI passthrough" would be impossible)

Comment: Can you elaborate why in such case ACPI doesn't make sense? It really surprises me.

Comment: @0andriy: It's more about which market segment they're targeting - if it's such a crippled joke that it can't handle more than one PCI_E bus (more correctly "bus segment") then it's likely to be intended for a "not PC compatible bargain basement disposable" embedded market and unlikely have anything significantly more expensive to develop/maintain (ACPI).

Comment: Then can you clarify this in your answer? Because now categorical “doesn’t make sense” is simple (from engineering prospective) not true.